# Simple connectedness criterion in the plane

Tags: algebraic-topology, connectedness

In Rotman’s An Introduction to Algebraic Topology, chap.3, p.49, he cites the result:

Given an open connected subset $U$ of $S^2$ $(= \mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\})$ and a base point $u_0$, $\pi_1(U, u_0) =\{1\}$ iff $S^2 \setminus U$ is connected.

He says that this result takes some work to prove & doesn’t seem to prove it in the book but I could be wrong. Can a proof or a reference for this result be suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Since $U$ is open and connected, it must be path-connected, and any two connected components of $S^2 \setminus U$ will be separated. So if $S^2 \setminus U$ has at least 2 connected components, any loop in $U$ that circles one of them will not be null-homotopic.

Picture for reference: Here is an open set $U$ (blue) where the complement $S^2 \setminus U$ (yellow) has multiple connected components:
[image]

Take a loop $\gamma$ in $U$ that circles one of the connected components of $S^2 \setminus U$ and pick a point $p \in S^2 \setminus U$:

[image]

**There cannot be a null-homotopy of $\gamma$ that stays inside $U$ the entire time.** If there was, that would imply $\Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ p \}$ was simply connected: we could homotope any loop in $\Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ p \}$ that circled $p$ so that its image matched the image $\gamma$, and then apply our null homotopy (which deforms this loop entirely within the blue region) to shrink this loop to a point. But we know $\pi_1(\Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ p \}) \cong \Bbb{Z}$ is nontrivial.

We started by assuming $S^2 \setminus U$ had multiple connected components and ended by using this fact to show that $U$ contains loops which cannot be shrunk to a point inside $U$. This shows that, when $S^2 \setminus U$ has multiple connected components, $\pi_1(U)$ is nontrivial. This is the contrapositive of Rotman's statement, which is that $\pi_1(U)$ being the trivial group implies $S^2 \setminus U$ is connected.

Comment: Thanks very much. Intuitively your argument is clear to me. Two points which aren’t: (1) can we guarantee the existence of such a loop when $U$ has more than one component (2) how can we prove that such a curve can’t be nullhomotopic?

Comment: $U$ is open and connected, that means it only has a single component.

Comment: Not if it’s an open band circling the sphere.

Comment: A loop that goes around a connected component of $S^2 \setminus U$ cannot be nulhomotopic in $U$, because for any point in $S^2 \setminus U$ inside the loop, this would mean that a loop containing the point was nulhomotopic without ever crossing the point, which is impossible.

Comment: @User2020 You're thinking of the case when $S^2 \setminus U$ has multiple components. That open band $U$ itself is just one component. If it's open and has multiple components, it's not connected by definition.

Comment: An annulus in the plane has 2 components and is nevertheless connected.

Comment: The complement of the annulus has two components. The annulus itself is a single component.

Comment: I got it. I had typed $U$ when I meant $U^c$. Obviously $U$ being connected has only one component! But my questions remain.

Comment: @User2020 Added some pictures, hopefully that helps clarify!

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the trouble to draw the pix. Just one sticking point for me: can we guarantee there’s a component of U^c which is “surrounded” by U? If we just assume it, it seems to be tantamount to assuming the result IMO. And how would one define “surrounds” in S^2?

Comment: "Can we guarantee there’s a component of $U^c$ which is “surrounded” by $U$?" This is guaranteed by working in $S^2$ rather than $\Bbb{R}^2$. In $\Bbb{R}^2$, for instance, $U$ could be the infinite vertical strip $(0, 1) \times \Bbb{R}$, and then $\Bbb{R}^2 \setminus U$ has two components, but $U$ is obviously simply connected. But in $S^2$, this $U$, and the two components of its complement $S^2 \setminus U$, are all dense in a neighborhood of the point $\infty$. "Surrounded" just means there's a loop in $U$ with nontrivial winding number about a point in $S^2 \setminus U$.

Comment: Sounds plausible but I guess I need to convince myself that the argument works in a technically rigorous way for very general connected open subsets of S^2.

Comment: By compactness of $S^2$ we can without meaningful loss of generality assume that we are in the case when $S^2 \setminus U$ has 2 connected components and that one of them contains the point at ∞. (Cover the bounded components of $S^2 \setminus U$ by closed balls disjoint from the unbounded component, in such a way as to connect them all into one big closed bounded component.) Then the argument/picture given above is sufficient and in no way lacks technical rigor.